# Can regular python modules like random and time be used with kivy to make android apps?

Tags: android, python, kivy, python-module

If not could you tell me the kivy equivalent to time.sleep please?

Comment: sure you can ... but I doubt it will do what you want(at least `time.sleep` as it will block your entire UI ... this looks like its frozen for the duration of the sleep)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `random` and `time` in `Kivy` but you shouldn't use `time.sleep` because it stops not only your function but also all functions in Kivy. You should use `events` or `timers` like [kivy.clock](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html)